# How to write a generic non-member wrapper around arbitrary member functions?

Tags: c++, c++14, metaprogramming, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

## Problem

Have a template that generates a wrapper for an arbitrary member function that allows to invoke that function on an object, e.g.:

Given `bool std::string::empty()`, the wrapper to be generated would be `bool wrapper(const std::string& str) { return str.empty(); }`.

The wrapper function shall not be a lambda (so that it can be passed as function pointer).

## My approach (for non-const member functions)

```
/* Wrapper (for non-const member functions) */

template<typename T, typename R, typename... ARGS>
struct staticWrapperHelper
{
    using fType = R (T::*)(ARGS...);
    template<fType FUNCTION>
    static R wrapper(T& object, ARGS... args) { return object.*FUNCTION(args...); }
};

template<typename T, typename R, typename... ARGS>
auto staticWrapper(R (T::*memberFunction)(ARGS...))
{
    //auto function = [memberFunction] (T& object, ARGS... args) -> R { return (object.*memberFunction)(args...); };
    using Helper = staticWrapperHelper<T, R, ARGS...>;

    R (*wrapper)(T&, ARGS...) = &Helper::template wrapper<R (T::*)(ARGS...)>;
    return wrapper;
}

/* Example */

class A
{
public:
    void member() {}
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    auto f = staticWrapper<A>(&A::member);
    f(a);

    return 0;
}
```

## Issue with my approach

It does not compile. It seems like the returned wrapper is still a template: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4c0dd9ab631aa1f

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'auto staticWrapper(R (T::*)(ARGS ...)) [with T = A; R = void; ARGS = {}]':
main.cpp:32:41:   required from here
main.cpp:17:9: error: no matches converting function 'wrapper' to type 'void (*)(class A&)'
   17 |     R (*wrapper)(T&, ARGS...) = &Helper::template wrapper;
      |         ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:8:14: note: candidate is: 'template static R staticWrapperHelper::wrapper(T&, ARGS ...) [with R (T::* FUNCTION)(ARGS ...) = FUNCTION; T = A; R = void; ARGS = {}]'
    8 |     static R wrapper(T& object, ARGS... args) { return object.*FUNCTION(args...); }
      |              ^~~~~~~
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution I can accept by passing the member function pointer as template argument, which -- unfortunately -- requires the type to be explicitly mentioned in C++14 (a helper macro can help here). The signature of the function pointer is then broken down by a helper function in order to create the wrapper.

```
#include <iostream>

/* Wrapper (for non-const member functions) */

template<typename PTM, PTM ptm>
struct staticWrapper
{
    constexpr static auto make()
    {
        return breakDownAndWrap(ptm);
    }

private:
    template<typename C, typename R, typename... ARGS>
    constexpr static auto breakDownAndWrap(R (C::*)(ARGS...))
    {
        R (*wrapper)(C&, ARGS...) = &Wrapper<C, R, ARGS...>::get;
        return wrapper;
    }

    template<typename C, typename R, typename... ARGS>
    struct Wrapper
    {
        constexpr static R get(C& obj, ARGS... args)
        {
            return (obj.*ptm)(args...);
        }
    };
};

/* Optional helper macro */

#define AUTO_T(val) decltype(val), val

/* Example */

class A
{
public:
    int number;

    void member() { std::cout << number << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A a {2};
    auto f = staticWrapper<decltype(&A::member), &A::member>::make();
    auto g = staticWrapper<AUTO_T(&A::member)>::make();
    f(a);
    g(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Working example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c5cb1d98437c789

Comment: In C++17 you can have `template <auto ptm>`

Answer (score 2):

Regarding `using fType = R (T::*)(ARGS...);`, type `fType` is a pointer type, so it can't be used as a template parameter in order to memorize/save the instance method address at runtime to be used later. So, you should define a member in `staticWrapperHelper` to save the method pointer to be used later:

```
template<typename T, typename R, typename... ARGS>
struct staticWrapperHelper
{
    using fType = R (T::*)(ARGS...);
    fType method;
    R operator() (T& object, ARGS... args) { return (object.*method)(args...); }
};
```

Also I changed `wrapper` static method to an instance method: `operator()` to be a functor object.

Now, in the `staticWrapper` function that works as a factory function for `staticWrapperHelper`, we return an instance of `staticWrapperHelper` that stores the method pointer. This instace object can be used later to invoke the instance method on the supplied object of type `T`.

```
template<typename T, typename R, typename... ARGS>
auto staticWrapper(R (T::*memberFunction)(ARGS...))
{
    using Helper = staticWrapperHelper<T, R, ARGS...>;
    return Helper{.method = memberFunction};
}
```

Live demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a7b7c04b36d9dc0

Comment: I made a mistake, intended to take the address of `Helper::template wrapper<memberFunction>`instead of `Helper::template wrapper<R (T::*)(ARGS...)>`; and yes, as `memberFunction` is a function argument I cannot use it as template parameter for `staticWrapperHelper` here, although in general, function pointers can be template parameters.

Comment: Now to your solution (thank you!): I was sceptical about having to have an instance here first, but it seems that the whole thing can be constexpr so this is no issue to me. However, while the functor that is returned may be callable, it cannot be used as a function pointer.

Comment: @haku As you stated, template parameters must be known at compile time, so a function pointer that is passed via a function argument can't be used for template parameter. A thing that comes to my mind is making the `staticWrapper` function a `constexpr` function, but I'm not sure that could be a solution or not.

Comment: I found a way which takes the function pointer both as template parameter and (later) as function parameter - the latter to break down the signature into class, return type and arguments. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60225302/10614843

Comment: @haku Good. It looks like the same idea I proposed above; making the factory method a `constexpr` function.